# how to convert lines of json into a hashmap of composite keys?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

Background on the actual problem: I am trying to create an AWS Lambda function in Python that accumulates records from a DynamoDB stream into an S3 object. If you don't understand this context you can just ignore it, the question is really a pure Python question.

I got the code below barely working, the file is successfully concatenated with new records from the stream, in the desired format (one JSON object per line). But what I really want is to treat the file as a hashmap, using the fields in `keys` (4th line of the function definition), which are a subset of the fields in `new`, so that any records coming in will overwrite old records containing the same key values.

What is the obvious / idiomatic way to change the line `journal += data` so that instead of a concatenation, I get an overwrite of lines of the same `keys` value?

```
import json
import boto3
import re
import uuid
from decimal import Decimal
import six
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    object = s3.Object('some.bucket', 'address/dynamo-stream.json')
    journal = object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8') 
    for record in event['Records']:
        keys = record['dynamodb'].get('Keys')
        new = record['dynamodb'].get('NewImage')
        if new:
            data = json.dumps(loads(new))
            journal += data + "\n"
    object.put(Body=journal)                
    return "ok"

# below: code from https://github.com/Alonreznik/dynamodb-json/blob/master/dynamodb_json/json_util.py

[...]

def loads(s, as_dict=False, *args, **kwargs):

[...]
```

More explanation:

The variable `keys` is a subset of `new` in the sense that, for any json value of `new` in the format

```
{ "k1":"v1", "k2:v2", "k3:v3", ... "kN:vN" }
```

`keys` will have the value

```
{ "k1":"v1", "k2:v2" }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, but perhaps you are looking for the [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method?

Comment: @IonicSolutions I guess `dict.update()` could work, but first I would have to build a `dict` object

Comment: `dict.setdefault(key, value)` should do the job

Comment: @Alex R Why is that an issue?